# MongoServerError: unknown operator: $date

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to upsert a record in MongoDB from nodejs. The JSON I am trying to insert is:

```
{
  _id: { '$date': '2017-02-14T00:00:00Z' },
  dayType: 'weekday',
  endOfMonth: false,
  finEndOfMonth: false,
  _entity: [ 'holiday' ]
}
```

And I am getting this error: **(MongoServerError: unknown operator: $date)**
Why is that happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `$date` is not an operator to be used while inserting.

If you need to insert `_id` as `date` use one of predefined constructors

[Reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Date/)

[Sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9DnCtzsiW5b)

You could use `new Date("2017-02-14T00:00:00Z")`